# Method not found DbEntityEntry.get_State()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

- VS2012
- EF 6.0.2

I have a method call as follows which generates the exception **Method not found: 'System.Data.EntityState System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry.get_State()** when I make the call **dataRepository.Update(platformUser);**:

```
 public void LoginDelete(string aUserName)
        {
            MembershipUser loginToDelete = Membership.GetUser(aUserName);

            if (loginToDelete != null)
            {
                using (DataRepository dataRepository = DataRepository.Instance())
                {
                    using (TransactionScope transaction = dataRepository.Transaction())
                    {
                        string userMembershipId = loginToDelete.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
                        PlatformUser platformUser = dataRepository.SingleOrDefault<PlatformUser>(r => r.MembershipUserId == userMembershipId);

                        if (platformUser != null)
                        {
                            platformUser.MembershipUserId = "";
                            dataRepository.Update<PlatformUser>(platformUser);
                            dataRepository.Save();
                        }

                        Membership.DeleteUser(aUserName);

                        transaction.Complete();
                    }
                }
```

and my data repository is defined as follows:

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _DataContext;

    public EntityFrameworkRepository(DbContext aDataContext)
    {
        _DataContext = aDataContext;
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return _DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T SingleOrDefault<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> aPredicate) where T : class
    {
        return _DataContext.Set<T>()
                           .SingleOrDefault(aPredicate);
    }


    public TransactionScope Transaction(TransactionScopeOption aTransactionScopeOption = TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
        IsolationLevel aIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)
    {
        return new TransactionScope(aTransactionScopeOption,
            new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = aIsolationLevel
            }
            );
    }

    public void Update<T>(T aEntity) where T : class
    {
        DbEntityEntry entityEntry = _DataContext.Entry(aEntity);
        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _DataContext.Set<T>()
                        .Attach(aEntity);
            entityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public DbContext DataContext
    {
        get { return _DataContext; }
    }

}

public class DataRepository : EntityFrameworkRepository, IDisposable, IDataRepository
{
    public DataRepository()  : base(new DataContext())
    {
    }

    public static DataRepository Instance()
    {
        return new DataRepository();
    }

}
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting the exception and how I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I still had an old reference to EF 5 floating around which was causing the issue. Once I made sure that was also EF 6.0.2 all was well.